# Java not reading "&&" statements properly?

Tags: java, logical-operators

I'm having a problem with my Java code.  Specifically, one of my if statements containing an `&&` is not returning True for certain inputs like I expect it to.

The snippet in question:

```
if (num%2==1 && num < 0) {       //why is not reading this statement?
    negodd ++;
}
```

Sample inputs and outputs vs expected outputs:

```
 Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop :
 1
 2
-2
-1
 0   // not counted as a number since it is a stop function.

Output of my code.                     What it should be.
You Entered 4 numbers :               You Entered 4 numbers :
1 negative even                         1 negative even
1 positive even                         1 positive even                         
0 negative odd                          1 negative odd  <--should read the 1
1 positive odd                          1 positive odd
```

The full code in case that helps:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class stupid {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
         int num = 0;
         int negodd = 0, count = 0, posseven = 0;
         int possodd = 0; int negeven=0;

         System.out.println("Enter any number to continue. Enter 0 to stop : ");
         num = x.nextInt();

         if(num==0){
             System.out.print("You immediately stop");
             System.exit(0);
         }

         while (num != 0) {
             count ++;
             if (num%2==1 && num > 0) {
                 possodd ++;
             } 
             if (num%2==1 && num < 0) {       //why is not reading this statement?
                 negodd ++;
             }
             if (num%2==0 && num > 0) {
                 posseven ++;
             }
             if (num%2==0 && num < 0) {
                 negeven++;
             }
             num = x.nextInt();
         }
         System.out.printf("You Entered %d numbers\n",count);
         System.out.printf("%d negative even \n",negeven);
         System.out.printf("%d positive even\n",posseven);
         System.out.printf("%d negative odd\n",negodd);
         System.out.printf("%d positive odd\n",possodd);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than calling `System.exit(0)`, try simply returning from the method using a `return`.

Comment: Um i'm still new in to programming and if i put new stuff in my program my professor will not record my work as correct. still learning a lot here in this website. :)

Comment: It is reading it correctly, but `num % 2` will never be `1` for a negative number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the modulo operator with negative numbers gives you a different result than you might think.

```
1 % 2 == 1
2 % 2 == 0
-2 % 2 == 0
-1 % 2 == -1
```

To get the result you want, you can replace your modulo tests with `num % 2 == 0` and `num % 2 != 0`.

Comment: Okay , one more thing how do i print this line "You entered a positive even number" ? when the user enters 2 and then 0.

Comment: same with the others like -1 then 0 then it should print "You entered a negative odd number".

Comment: Well, because your `num` variable is overwritten when you enter 0, you have to store the previous value in a new variable. When you leave the while-loop, you then have to check if that variable is either positive or negative.

Comment: Can you please explain more like i put count =1 then if num > 0? thats the logical error im getting i think it doesn't perform the num

Comment: my condition is if(count==1 && num >0) {
sout.(you entered a pos numb); 
i tried this  but it just skips this condition

Comment: Actually it should be `num % 2 == 0` and `num % 2 != 0`, you don't need `Math.abs` BTW `Math.abs` can return a negative number ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, that is better. It also avoids the corner case of Integer.MIN_VALUE. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 % 2 == 1
2 % 2 == 0
-2 % 2 == 0
-1 % 2 == -1
```

Here, `-1%2` does not results in 1. Hence, it will not increment value of `negodd` variable.

In `JAVA`, negative number modulo will give same result as positive number modulo but with a negative sign. 0 is neutral thus it will not have any sign.

Answer (score 0):

-1 % 2 is going to return -1, not 1, where -2 % 2 will give a result of 0.